# Gatsby "variantsValue is not iterable" error after configuring Tailwind 2 variants?

Tags: gatsby, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind 2 with Gatsby.

I want to apply the class `odd:flex-row-reverse`, but the [Tailwind docs say](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#odd-child):

> By default, the odd-child variant is not enabled for any core plugins.

So I've configured the "odd-child" variant to work with `marginLeft`:

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  variants: {
    extend: {
      flexDirection: ['odd'],
      marginLeft: ['odd'],  // This line causes the error
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

But for some reason, I'm getting the following errors in the console while using `gatsby develop`:

```
error Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

variantsValue is not iterable
failed Re-building development bundle - 0.232s
```

Everything runs fine if I remove the `marginLeft` line.

Why does the `marginLeft` variant cause errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is because `marginLeft` isn't a core plugin. The core plugin for margins is simply `margin`. You should edit your Tailwind config to look like this:

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  variants: {
    extend: {
      flexDirection: ['odd'],
      margin: ['odd'],  // `margin` instead of `marginLeft`
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

You can get a full list of the default variants for each of the core plugins [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuring-variants#default-variants-reference).